# Python file import doesn't appear in namespace prior to exception, but does after exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a snippet of Python code that throws an exception "No module named 'common_functions'" when I try to import the file "common_functions.py" from folder API.

```
def validate_config():
    try:
        import API
        logger.debug(dir(API))
        from API.common_functions import get_dbusername
    except Exception as e:
        import API
        logger.debug(dir(API))
        from API.common_functions import get_dbusername
```

When I look at the output of the logging of the modules present in API initially it is:

```
 [..., 'config', 'external_config_operations']
```

but in the exception the missing module is present:

```
[ ..., 'common_functions', 'config','external_config_operations']
```

I've tried clearing out all cached files and for some reason this is still happening. Does anyone know why module discovery is working this way?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: No module named 'common_functions'. I'll update the post to clarify

Comment: Please post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: It's weird that you'd try the problem code again in the exception handler.

Comment: Whether `import API` is expected to give you `common_functions` on its own depends on the contents of `API/__init__.py`, which you aren't currently showing us.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.